# Microsoft SQL Browser Client

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there any free clients in which I can browse MS SQL Databases...?

Comment: You can try QueryExpress( http://www.albahari.com/queryexpress.aspx ),LinqPad( http://www.linqpad.net/ ) too...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Take a look at [Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=c243a5ae-4bd1-4e3d-94b8-5a0f62bf7796)

Comment: Should get newer version than 2005, in case he/she wants to browse 2008/2008R2 servers. Choose from 32-bit or 64-bit at this page: http://www.microsoft.com/express/Database/InstallOptions.aspx

Comment: Are there any lighter tools available for Java developer?

Comment: Those old links don't work any more. Try this newer link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/overview-sql-tools

Answer (score 18):

Try HeidiSQL http://www.heidisql.com/ - it's open source and does both MSSQL and MySQL. It is very well featured.

(just a note as of Aug 2013 the author is working on MS Azure MSSQL access but it's not working yet)

Answer (score 7):

A lightweight alternative - which also allows browisng of other databases - is [SqlDbx](http://www.sqldbx.com).  The Personal Edition is free.

Comment: Thanks, if the studio slows me down ill give this a try